# VLAN subset of LAN?

Tags: vlan, local-area-network

I'm reading up on VLAN and came across this

"VLAN's allow a network manager to logically segment a LAN into different broadcast domains"

If I'm understanding this correctly VLAN is always less than or equals to LAN in terms of number of workstations and is limited by the boundary of the LAN i.e 2 workstations from different LANs can't belong in the same VLAN?  If someone would clarify this would be great.

Comment: I think the excellent answers that are appearing to this question really clarify that it's unanswerable, because you haven't defined "*LAN*".

Comment: The article defined it as "a single broadcast domain".

Comment: Layer 2 (ethernet broadcast) or layer 3 (IP broadcast)?

Comment: They also don't say.  I might infer something, but honestly, we're dealing with imponderables at this point.  I really don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: If I could downvote this twice, I would

Comment: To be technically correct: Endpoints don't belong to VLAN's. Ports belong to VLAN's. Endpoints get plugged into ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is wrong.

A VLAN is another layer. You can have multiple LAN's (I assume you mean SUBNET here?) in the same VLAN.

Comment: Yes; you might not wish all the machines connected to a given layer-2 contiguous switch fabric to be able to talk to each other without interposing a layer-3 transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, a VLAN can extend across multiple LANs, or divide one physical LAN in to multiple virtual ones. It's not limited by the physical constraints by any means.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's true, depending on your definition of a LAN.  If you define it as "*a layer-2 contiguous switch fabric*", then I think the original statement is precise and true.  If, say, you define it as "*IP broadcast domain*", I agree with you.

Comment: Yeah, the definition is certainly unclear, though if you consider trunks, and VLANs over tunnels of various sorts to make a contiguous switch fabric (I'm not in disagreement) it would end up being a subsection.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers provided above - while correct - are over-thinking the problem as posed, bearing in mind the document at the root of the question is over 16 years old (It still uses HUBS to connect devices - which shows the simplicity and age of what is talking about), and posits the introduction that a LAN are computers directly connected devices which do not traverse a router.    Of key importance - 802.1q was still in draft.

Thus to answer @Madhatter the link given posits an ethernet broadcast domain.

Given the constraints the answer is that the OP's understanding is correct - a VLAN "is always less than or equals to LAN in terms of number of workstations and is limited by the boundary of the LAN" - by the definition given for a LAN.

I'm not sure that this is really a question for serverfault though.